# How to eager loading multiple associations with multiple where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure whether it is possible to do this or not. But with this schema

Transactions : **id | reference | topup_id | redeem_id**

Topups : **id | status | amount**

Redemptions : **id | status | amount**

I have set up the one-to-one connection between these table because each of the topup or redemption can be referred to only one single transaction record.

Generally, this is how the transaction table looks like in case of topup

```
ID | reference | topup_id | redeem_id
1  |   ESID1   |     1    |   NULL
```

and for the redemption

```
ID | reference | topup_id | redeem_id
1  |   ESID1   |   NULL   |    1
```

You can see that is the topup transaction, the topup_id will exist and the record associated in topups table is referred while redeem_id will exist and the record in redemptions table is referred in case of redemption transaction.

Now I want to count all status in both topup and redemption table with the value of '00'. Currently, I do this without any success

```
result = Transaction.includes(:topup, :redeem).where(topup: {status: '00'}, redeem: {status: '00'}).count
```

It returns nothing

Please help me find the solution of this issue

Comment: Well in your query you are missing a " ' " after 00. I guess is just a typo when you copied the query, but I'll point that out just in case it is the problem.

Comment: Ohhh! that's my typo error. Thank you very much for the comment

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of topups/redemptions with status "00" and with a transaction:

```
Transaction.
joins("LEFT JOIN topups on topups.id = transactions.topup_id").
joins("LEFT JOIN redemptions on redemptions.id = transactions.redeem_id").
where("topups.status = ? OR redemptions.status = ?", "00", "00").
count
```

From the information that you have provided it looks like a transaction can belong to either a topup or a redemption. In that case, I would have implemented the following schema:

Transactions : id | reference | payable_id | payable_type

Topups : id | status | amount

Redemptions : id | status | amount

Answer (score -1):

The **includes** method receives as arguments the names of the associations, so for instance if your model `has_many topups` the argument should be `:topup`, but if it `has_one topup` the argument should be `:topup`.

On the other hand the **where** method uses table names, which by convention in Rails are always plural.

Therefore your query I believe should be:

```
Transaction.includes(:topup, :redeem).where(topups: {status: '00'}).where(redeems: {status: '00'})
```

Also if you only need to retrieve the transaction given those conditions but you won't need to use the topup or redeem data consider using **joins** instead of **includes**.